# Is Napkee worth it?

Tags: user-interface, balsamiq

[Napkee](http://www.napkee.com/index.php) claims to:

> Export Balsamiq Mockups to HTML/CSS/JS
>   and Adobe Flex 3 at a click of a
>   button.
>
> - Balsamiq's perfect companion
> - No coding skills required
> - Pays for itself after one use

If it really "works" Napkee could be extremely useful.

Does Napkee work as advertised? What is the quality of the exported HTML?
Is it a must-have companion to Balsamiq (which I love)?

Comment: See the list of tools that work with balsamiq here:  http://balsamiq.com/support/community  e.g. balsamiq to html, balsamiq to android etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it, the Flex exporting seems good, but the HTML exporting is bad, component location is not accurate.

Now I am using [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com/), it can create mockups like balsamiq and also able to export working html.

Answer (score 2):

I recently imported some linked Balsamiq mockups into Napkee with the goal of creating a click-through HTML demo.  Napkee did not work as advertised.  I sent an email (with attachments) to the Napkee team and did not get a response.  The video tutorial on Napkee's site is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

it's Enrico from Napkee here :)
I should not say if it works or not but please keep in mind that new versions are published weekly bringing new features and fixing layout problems that Napkee may have!

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Napkee is worth it, because it allows users to export their creativity from Mockups, Balsamiq that is, and work with them interactively.

Answer (score 0):

Try, [appsketcher](http://www.appsketcher.com). It claims same as Napkee does. But You'll have to design prototype in itself. It doesn't support BMML files.

But it reminds me working on Dreamweaver and other drag-n-drop applications specially made for developing HTML templates.